# Need advice on database tables merging tool

Tags: c#

I have created a tool that is using Excel (VBA) currently, however I would like to make it independent from Excel as there might be different kind of problems with Excel update packages etc. Basically to eliminate one more factor that can go wrong.

My current Excel application:

1. Imports two database tables (Customers) into two different worksheets `sheet1` and `sheet2`
2. Merging these two tables to another `sheet3` by comparing column 2 (Name) and 6 (Postanumber)
3. If there are duplicates (there are partly same Customers in both of them) VBA code inputs only one value to `sheet3`
4. After `sheet3` is ready I am performing `foreach` loop for `sheet3` for exporting all the Customers to another system

I have started with C# code that is able to connect to database and get all the Customers from both tables by merging them.

Started with DataGrid to get an idea:

```
private Task<DataView> GetDataAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {

        string connectionStringDE = "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=DE875;dbq=@DEDBFS;Uid=DEUsername;Pwd=DEPassword;";
        string queryStringDE = "select NRO,NAME,NAMEA,NAMEB,ADDRESS,POSTA,POSTN,POSTADR,COMPANYN,COUNTRY,ID,ACTIVE from COMPANY";
        string connectionStringFR = "Driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};ServerName=FR875;dbq=@FRDBFS;Uid=FRUsername;Pwd=FRPassword;";
        string queryStringFR = "select NRO,NAME,NAMEA,NAMEB,ADDRESS,POSTA,POSTN,POSTADR,COMPANYN,COUNTRY,ID,ACTIVE from COMPANY";

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("COMPANY");
        // using-statement will cleanly close and dispose unmanaged resources i.e. IDisposable instances
        using (OdbcConnection dbConnectionDE = new OdbcConnection(connectionStringDE))
        {
            dbConnectionDE.Open();
            OdbcDataAdapter dadapterDE = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            dadapterDE.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(queryStringDE, dbConnectionDE);

            dadapterDE.Fill(dataTable);

        }
        using (OdbcConnection dbConnectionFR = new OdbcConnection(connectionStringFR))
        {
            dbConnectionFR.Open();
            OdbcDataAdapter dadapterFR = new OdbcDataAdapter();
            dadapterFR.SelectCommand = new OdbcCommand(queryStringFR, dbConnectionFR);

            var newTable = new DataTable("COMPANY");
            dadapterFR.Fill(newTable);

            dataTable.Merge(newTable);

        }

        return dataTable.DefaultView;
    });
}
```

However because of lack of knowledge I am not so confident what method should I use in C# to store all the data (`sheet3`, there are more than 1000 records) before exporting to another system with `foreach`? Should I create local database or can use list? I guess I shouldn't import all the values from two tables to two different lists/database tables and compare/merge them after to another one (like I am doing in my current Excel VBA setup), but can perform this action on connection, merging and assigning to list/database table?

Comment: A good architecture would be to separate the business logic from the data access; you can create a standard model that you use for the business logic, then you can fill that model getting data from where you wish

Comment: @Steve this is a really good question! Basically if Name and Postanumber are the same, then it means that it is the same Customer. All fields should match in this case. However data is kept up to date manually so there can be human mistakes. So basically this is an error case. Should be taking in consideration for error handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However because of lack of knowledge I am not so confident what method should I use in C# to store all the data (sheet3, there are more than 1000 records) before exporting to another system with foreach?

"What should I use" is subjective/opinion based and can't really be answered here. It would be fair to say that anything you can find a reasonable tutorial on such as generic collections or datasets/datatables will be able to easily handle a dataset this small

> Should I create local database or can use list?

You can do either, but I would only use a database if i was persisting the information. It sounds to me like your need for data storage is temporary so I would just use an in-memory collection of data

> I guess I shouldn't import all the values from two tables to two different lists/database tables and compare/merge them after to another one

I can't see any reason why you shouldn't

> but can perform this action on connection, merging and assigning to list/database table?

It is certainly possible to merge two sets of data by uploading one if them into the database where the other one is and having the database do the merge

Comment: So in this particular case database is not needed and values can be stored in memory (List) each time when running an export? Also I understood that creating two separate lists from two database tables and building a third one with ready output for exporting is the way to go?

Comment: You've already got a datatable based solution (I hadn't seen that edit when i wrote my answer).. How does it not meet your needs?